# MS Graph API: How to get webUrl to student submission page for teacher

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-edu

I can easily get *webUrl* for the Teams assignment page:
[image: MS Graph explorer]

How can I get similar property (or some workaround) for the submission page:
[image: MS Teams WEB version]?

I can't see it in [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/educationsubmission?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) of the submission.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The webUrl for the student submission page can be achieved with a simple tweak to the requestURL. In the requestURL you can add /submissions after the assignments/{{assignmentID}} to get all the submissions from the teacher's side for the selected assignment.

Comment: >>I can't see it in properties of the submission.